# Where is the mistake of the proof of mine?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have tried several times but in vain.

I am willing to find out the number of group homomorphisms from the dihedral group $D_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{18}$. I have done something but I am not sure at all if it is correct. Would you please help me to me correct solution ?

Any group homomorphism $\rho:D_{12}\rightarrow \mathbb Z_{18}$ will be completely determined by $\rho(r), \rho(f)$ if $$D_{12}=\{r, f: r^{12}=f^2=(rf)^2=e\}$$

here $|\rho(r)|$ divides $|r|, |\mathbb Z_{18}|$ i.e. $(12, 18)=6$. Hence $|\rho(r)|\in \{1,2, 3, 6\}$ i.e. $\rho(r)\in\{0, 9, 6, 12, 3, 15\}$.

Similarly $|\rho(f)|\in\{1, 2\}$ i.e. $\rho(f)\in \{0, 9\}$.

Now we have to check if $\rho((rf)^2)=\rho(1)$ i.e. 
\begin{align}
&2\rho(r)+2\rho(f)=0~(\mod 18)...........................(\ast)
\end{align}
 is satisfied or not.

If $\rho(f)=0 $ then only choice for $\rho(r)$ is 0, 9. So here we shall get 2 group homomorphism.

If $\rho(f)=9$ then $(\ast)$ gives $\rho(r)=0, 9$. So another two group homomorphisms.

Which means $\#Hom(D_{12}, \mathbb Z_{18})=2+2=4$

Am I right this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: consider the map $h: D_{12}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the conditions $$h(r)=9, \quad h(f)=9.$$ Is this a homomorphism? If so, how did it escape your net? Thinking about this example will help you find the right argument.

Comment: +1 Nice hint. I think OP uses $|\rho(x)|$ to mean the order of $\rho(x)$, in which case I do not think there is any confusion of order and value.

Comment: Agree with @Servaes. $|\rho(x)|$ has been used just to denote the order.

Comment: And thank you . I got my mistake

Comment: Quite right, edited.